# Viewer Application: Allow users to open pdf/doc etc without pdf reader/office

Tags: c, file, format, converters, viewer

I am a trying to write a hobby project that allows users to package files like pdf (later docx) as executables that can be viewed on other machines without pdf readers. The most common way is to convert it into another format (for which you have an application installed).

I am thinking about creating an ".exe". The idea is to develop a C application that takes pdf file as input and makes the functions calls that a pdf-reader (library not yet decided) makes to "open" & "display" a pdf.

Then I can compile this into an ".exe" that can be run on any PC to display this particular file.

I just wanted to ask you guys if this makes sense or is utterly stupid?

Comment: I think it is stupid. Not all PC can run ".exe", if it means the industry-standard executable file *for Windows*. I think converting to image, or pair of HTML and JavaScript if you want something executable, is better.

Comment: Creating something is fun, but will this project be useful? Why not simply install a PDF reader or modern web blowser that support viewing PDF?

Comment: Systems which don't have a pdf reader install will very likely not be able to run your "exe" anyway. Worse, you even keep them from reading the pdf with their reader as they cannot handle the surrounding "exe", thus cannot pass it to the normal reader. Sorry, but I have to agree with @MikeCAT.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just used "exe' to denote something that is executable on all Windows PCs (without using any application) e.g., to make something that displays an image without even using paint, just simple ext.

The output format I have no problem to changing, I just wanted to verify the validity of my approach.

Comment: Yes, and you make it unreadable on all other PCs. 1) "PC" is not just Windows! 2) There are much more computers other than "PC"s. 3) This is not a discussion forum. 4) Thus your "question" is off-topic. 5) I'm out for these reasons.

Comment: `PDF` is "Portable Document Format". So it is unwise to destroy that portability.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That is (has been?) common (and successful) practice of a large software company.

Comment: @Olaf it could be a interesting hobby project, but the ground is well covered. What would OP do when his distribution refuses to run after an OS upgrade?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think Imade my position quite clear with my first comment. I don't even think it is a good hobby project for exactly compatibility reasons. Another aspect is: which sane user with even some minor care for the stability of her system runs code from unreliable sources on a production system (or which admin allows that?)? What is wrong using standard formats? OP should better help spreading the readers or engage in the ODF.

Comment: @Olaf a hobby project isn't about compatibility. Consider "fishing". I don't judge anglers even though they don't take their fish to market: they just throw them back in. Not that I am supporting the objective here, it's the free choice of OP.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Just catching& hurting fish for fun? A normal angler would eat the fish. Anyway, I never disagreed it is a matter of personal opinion and I did not want to keep OP from doing it. Just my 2ct about useful/useless hobby projects. Sorry if I invoked a different impression.

Comment: @Olaf anglers say fish don't feel pain, but as I am neither fish nor angler I can't make any judgement. And so what if building a whale out of matchsticks is a useless project? At least the guy doing it has plenty of time to review his motivations!

Comment: @WeatherVane: Hmm, it is some kind of meditation. If I want to meditate, I design a schematic or route a PCB :-) But, hey, to each his own.